# converting epoch int from bytes in python

Tags: python

How can I convert 10 bytes epoch float in python?

```
 if struct.unpack('hq', s.get(b'data'))<time.time():
```

> struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 16

exact data is : `b'1595833579'`

tried with `'hhhhh'` but it returned `tuple()` like this `(13617, 13625, 13112, 13619, 14647)`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

if float(s.get(b'data').decode("utf-8"))<time.time(): solved

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to just call float on it? `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(data))` -> `datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 27, 8, 6, 19)`